# React js why is this.props.<myprop> undefined in sub component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I have a form component, and in it I have a roles and subroles component. The roles component works fine, but when I add the subroles component, this.props.roleList will be undefined when the render function runs. If I dont iterate through this.props.roleList in the subroles component during render, and just let it be, I can see that the prop will actually correctly be there. How can this be?

```
//The form itself, this is the component which contains state.
var SupplierForm = React.createClass({
    loadSupplierTemplateFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.getSupplierTemplateUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: true,
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({ supplierTemplate: data });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.getSupplierTemplateUrl, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    handleSupplierSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.registerSupplierUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: this.state.supplier,
            success: function() {
                //TODO: What now after supplier is registered?
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                //TODO: In case of errors, guide the user onwards based on type of error
                console.error(this.props.registerSupplierUrl, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            roleSelected: "Choose a role",
            subRoleSelected: "",
            supplierTemplate: []
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadSupplierTemplateFromServer();
    },

    updateState: function(stateObject) {
        this.setState(stateObject);
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="supplierForm">
                <form>
                    <h4 className="col-md-6 bifrost-formpart-header">Basic information</h4>
                    <div className="container col-md-6 bifrost-col-centered-top">
                        <BasicInformation basicInfo={this.state.supplierTemplate["Basic Information"]}
                                          updateState={this.updateState} />
                    </div>

                    <h4 className="col-md-6 bifrost-formpart-header">What is your occupation?</h4>
                    <div className="container col-md-6 bifrost-col-centered-bottom">
                        <Roles updateState={this.updateState}
                               roleList={this.state.supplierTemplate["_supplierTypes"]}
                               selectedRole={this.state.roleSelected}></Roles>
                    </div>

                    <h4 className="col-md-6 bifrost-formpart-header">What is your occupation?</h4>
                    <div className="container col-md-6 bifrost-col-centered-bottom">
                        <Subroles updateState={this.updateState}
                               roleList={this.state.supplierTemplate["_supplierTypes"]}
                               selectedRole={this.state.roleSelected}></Subroles>


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
      );
    }
});


//Basic information part of the form
var BasicInformation = React.createClass({
    handleBasicInfoChange: function(event) {
        var stateObject = function () {
            var returnObj = {};
            returnObj[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
            return returnObj;
        }.bind(event);

        this.props.updateState(stateObject);
    },

    render: function () {
        var fields = [];
        var keyCounter = 0;
        var keyName = "";

        for (var basickey in this.props.basicInfo) {
            if (this.props.basicInfo.hasOwnProperty(basickey)) {
                keyCounter = keyCounter + 1;
                keyName = "basic" + keyCounter;
                fields.push(
                    <input type={this.props.basicInfo[basickey]}
                           placeholder={basickey}
                           name={basickey}
                           onChange={this.handleBasicInfoChange}
                           className="form-control"
                           key={keyName}/>
                );
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="list-group">{fields}
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Roles = React.createClass({
    handleRoleSelection: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var stateObject = function () {
            var returnObj = {};
            returnObj["roleSelected"] = event.target.textContent;
            return returnObj;
        }.bind(event);

        this.props.updateState(stateObject);
    },

    render: function () {
        var roles = [];
        var keyCounter = 0;
        var keyName = "";

        for (var rolekey in this.props.roleList) {
            if (this.props.roleList.hasOwnProperty(rolekey)) {
                keyCounter = keyCounter + 1;
                keyName = "role" + keyCounter;
                roles.push(
                    <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleRoleSelection} key={keyName}>{rolekey}</a></li>
                );
            }
        }

        return (
            <div className="input-group">
                <div className="dropdown">
                    <button className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle bifrost-dropdown-button" type="button" id="rolesDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">{this.props.selectedRole}
                        <span className="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="rolesDropdown">{roles}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


var Subroles = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        console.log(this.props.roleList);
    },
    handleSubRoleSelection: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var stateObject = function () {
            var returnObj = {};
            returnObj["subRoleSelected"] = event.target.textContent;
            return returnObj;
        }.bind(event);

        this.props.updateState(stateObject);
    },

    render: function () {
        var subroles = [];
        var keyCounter = 0;
        var keyName = "";

        for (var subkey in this.props.roleList["_supplierTypes"]["Photography"]["_supplierSubTypes"]) {
            if (this.props.roleList["_supplierTypes"]["Photography"]["_supplierSubTypes"][subkey].hasOwnProperty(subkey)) {
                keyCounter = keyCounter + 1;
                keyName = "subrole" + keyCounter;
                subroles.push(
                    <button type="button" className="btn-sm btn-default col-md-5 bifrost-button" onClick={this.handleSubRoleSelection} key={keyName}>{subkey}</button>
                );
            }
        }

        return (
                <div className="btn-group btn-group-justified">{subroles}
                </div>
        );
    }
});


var Fields = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="input-group">
            </div>
        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <SupplierForm getSupplierTemplateUrl="/api/suppliers/GetSuppliersTemplate"
                registerSupplierUrl="/Account/RegisterSupplier" />, document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Comment: Well, when the component is rendered the first time, `this.state.supplierTemplate` is an empty array, so passing `this.state.supplierTemplate["_supplierTypes"]` to the children will in fact pass `undefined`. Only after the Ajax call returns, `this.state.supplierTemplate` *may* have such a property. Basically it's on you to properly handle the case when the data is not yet available.

Comment: Use the `getDefaultProps` lifecycle to set default values

Comment: So I have been playing around with it, and I tried checking that each part of this.props.roleList is not undefined inside the Subroles component, however, it still doesn't work. Afaik it should update when state is changed, which is the case upon a successful AJAX call. Any ideas?

Comment: By not working, I mean that the buttons for the Subroles component are never shown when the roleSelected changes.